# What count as a Parse request?

Tags: parse-platform

Because of the change of Terms, Parse now limits the number of requests a second, which is a good thing but does Parse Push and Parse Analytics count as requests ?

Comment: I don't even know, i wanted clear explication, maybe people thought it was a dumb question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Anytime you make a network call to Parse on behalf of your app via the iOS, Android, JavaScript, Windows, Xamarin, Unity, or REST API, it counts as an API request.

This does include things like finds, saves, logins, amongst other kinds of requests. It also includes requests to send push notifications, although this is seen as a single request regardless of how many recipients are targeted. Serving Parse files counts as an API request, including static assets served from Parse Hosting.

Analytics requests do have a special exemption. You can send us your analytics events any time without being limited by your app's request limit, as noted on [Parse's Plans page](https://www.parse.com/plans).

Comment: would this count as an API call `if (currentUser.username isEqualTo:@"james") {//do code here}`

Comment: I don't think so, because it means you already have the current user saved in your app

Comment: Do batch saves using saveAll count as 1 request or n requests?

Comment: So that means if you are using Push Notifications for a chat application, you are better going with a non-request based service, and not with Parse.com?

Comment: Push Notifications are separate from data plans @Léon Pelletier .  Please Correct me If am wrong.

Comment: And as mentionned above, does saveAll counts as 1 request or n requests?

Comment: @Hector Does loadInBackground count as a request too?

Comment: I mean ParseImageView.loadInBackground(). Or, equivalently, ParseFile.getDataInBackground().

Comment: @Hector, judging by these comments, I'd say this is still very unclear. How should I know when a parse function makes "a network call"? There should be a star in Parse documentation next to every function that counts as a request, or at the very least, a blog article with examples. This defines the difference between free and $5000/mo after all...

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link to official FAQ - https://parse.com/plans/faq

> What is considered an API request?
>
> In general, anytime you make a network call to Parse on behalf of your
>   app using one of the Parse SDKs or REST API, it counts as an API
>   request.
>
> What types of operations are counted as API requests?
>
> Queries, saves, logins, amongst other kinds of operations will be taken into account
>   when determining the number of requests generated by your app. A
>   request to send a push notification sent by a SDK will count as a
>   single request regardless of how many installations are targeted.
>   Batched requests will be counted based on the number of operations
>   performed in each batch. Serving Parse files counts as an API request,
>   including static assets served from Parse Hosting. Analytics requests
>   do not count towards your app's request limit.