# Include Key counts as API request? (PARSE)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I have a `final` parse query that include two subqueries and an `include:` key that fetches the data of a `PFUser`. In the storyboard class the `@"createdBy"` is a pointer to a `PFUser`, not the actual object itself. All of this results in one API request, correct?

```
PFQuery *images = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Storyboard"];
[images whereKeyExists:@"Image"];
[images whereKey:@"isPrivate" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false]];

PFQuery *dataQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Storyboard"];
[dataQuery whereKeyDoesNotExist:@"Image"];
[dataQuery whereKey:@"friendCollege" notEqualTo:@"College"];

PFQuery *final = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[images, dataQuery]];
[final includeKey:@"createdBy"];
[final orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[final setLimit:30];
[final findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error){
```

Comment: To answer your question, no. `includeKey` doesn't count against you, it's the network call that does. See my two previous answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27872929/2353523) & [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27754980/2353523) that will help you understand hopefully. I don't feel like typing another answer out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24565090/4988014) is an answer from Hector, explaining what an API request is. Basically everytime you make a call to the Parse servers, this counts as an API request.

To come back to your question: I'd say it is only one API request because you effectively make one complex query.

Comment: It is just one API request... @soulshined what do you mean.